# How to get selected text in a WebView Android?

Tags: android, text, webview

I'm building an app using a `Webview`. I want to get the selected text in my `Webview` when user select contextual menu item option.

If user click COPY option, i don't have problems for get text with the next lines:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData text_selected = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
```

But, if user select my custom item, it doesn't save text selected. I need to know the method for copy or detect selected text in `WebView`.

Thanks,